# Adobe AIR Android App 50MB limit

Tags: android, apache-flex, air, adobe, limit

I have an application built with Adobe AIR for Android. The apk is 108MB, larger than the 50MB limit imposed by Google. The instructions given here, http://developer.android.com/guide/market/expansion-files.html , are for native applications. Are there any similar instructions for Android AIR apps as well?

Answer (score 4):

You can use modules in Air, the same way that these expansion files work for APKs.

However, I have to question the size of the file beforehand.  108megs is *massive* for an application.  Never in my career have I seen an app bigger than 25megs total.  For it to be 108megs, you had to be particularly careless around file size optimizations and just kept piling in things that aren't needed inside the project.

Your best solution is to clean out the project and read up on filesize optimizations (like using vector based graphics instead of bitmaps).